# Inheritance polymorphism function call

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Shape 
{
   public:
      virtual void draw() const {cout<<"draw shape"<<endl;}
};



class Point : public Shape 
{
   public:
      Point( int a= 0, int b = 0 ) {x=a; y=b;}  // default constructor
      int getx() const {return x;}
      int gety() const {return y;}
      virtual void draw() const {cout<<"draw point("<<x<<","<<y<<")\n";}
   private:
      int x, y;   // x and y coordinates of Point
};


class Circle : public Point 
{
   public:  // default constructor
      Circle( double r = 0.0, int x = 0, int y = 0 ):Point(x,y) {radius=r;}
      virtual void draw() const 
      {cout<<"draw circle("<<getx()<<","<<gety()<<","<<radius<<")\n";}
   private:
      double radius;   // radius of Circle
};

void functionCall(Shape *arrayOfShapes[3])
{
    Shape shape;
    Point point( 7, 11 );            // create a Point
    Circle circle( 3.5, 22, 8 );     // create a Circle

    arrayOfShapes[0] = &shape;
    arrayOfShapes[1] = &point;
    arrayOfShapes[2] = &circle;

}

int main()
{


    Shape *arrayOfShapes[3];

    functionCall(arrayOfShapes);
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    arrayOfShapes[i]->draw();

    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run, a segmentation fault occured. It seems that the main function unable to retrieve the `arrayOfShapes[3]` object?

Is there a way to call a function passing in the a pointer of object and return the pointer of objects when its done?

Comment: **Never** store/leak out the address of a variable with *automatic storage-duration*, because those objects will cease to exist after their scope exists. The function `void functionCall(Shape* [3])` violates that.

Comment: @UnholySheep : No he isn't.  He is declaring `arrayOfShapes` as an array of pointers to shapes.  To do what you describe would be `Shape (*ptr_toarray)[3];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot create shapes in a local function like this, because putting addresses of local variables into an array makes them available outside their scope:

```
Shape shape;
arrayOfShapes[0] = &shape; // <<== Pointer to local
```

However, you can do this:

```
arrayOfShapes[0] = new Shape;
arrayOfShapes[1] = new Point( 7, 11 );
arrayOfShapes[2] = new Circle( 3.5, 22, 8 );
```

This approach creates shapes in *dynamic* memory, allowing them to be used when the function returns.

**Note:** Even though `Circle` needs an origin, a circle is definitely *not* a point. Therefore, this declaration is not logically sound:

```
class Circle : public Point // This implies that Circle is a Point
```

Although you can argue that a point is a circle with zero radius, structuring the inheritance like that would be a bad idea as well. A better approach is to make `Circle` *contain* a `Point` as its origin:

```
class Circle : public Shape 
{
   public:
      const Point origin;
      // default constructor
      Circle( double r = 0.0, int x = 0, int y = 0 ):origin(x,y),
 radius(r) {}
      virtual void draw() const 
      {cout<<"draw circle("<<origin.getx()<<","<<origin.gety()<<","<<radius<<")\n";}
   private:
      double radius;   // radius of Circle
};
```

Comment: If you're going to introduce `new`, you should also probably talk about `delete`.

Comment: How can i delete in such cases? delete shape?

Comment: @Justpee Yes, you call `delete arrayOfShapes[i]` for `i`s of 0, 1, and 2. In order for this to work correctly add `virtual ~Shape() {}` destructor to the base class.